# My Montserrat font is not showing the correct font-style

Tags: html, css, fonts

My **Montserrat** font is not showing the correct style. It is just normal. But if I add the style in the link it is going to work but I don't want the same style for everything. Like this:

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is the link and I want my h1 to be styled in **Montserrat Black** so I added:

```
h1 {
 font-family: "Montserrat-black";
}
```

But I am not seeing the effect . and if I add it here like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:black|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
```

The style black is going to be all over the page and I want it in only h1 so please help me out how do I go about it.

Answer (score 16):

Customize your font in [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?query=Ubu&selection.family=Montserrat:400,500,700,900%7CUbuntu:400,500,700) and use `font-weight: 300 | 500 | 700 | 900`:

[image]

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900; /* black */
}
```

```html
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700,900|Ubuntu:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

Font weights from Google fonts are selected as: `Montserrat:400,900` etc. 
Then in CSS specify this weight to use it.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 900; /* Black */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

<p>
  Normal body text
</p>

<h1>Black/ 900</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bootstrap and CSS it depends on which one is written first in the HTML code. I was experiencing the same issue for a simple reason that CSS code was first and Bootstrap below.

If your custom styles are not overriding the bootstrap styles, all you need to do is move the link to your custom stylesheet to a line after the bootstrap CDN link:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

This means that you first load the default bootstrap styles, then you can override some of those components with your own custom CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The old Google Fonts system is long gone.
Now you need to add font weight. The font family changed to default name. No extra things need to be added or changed but you need font weight to show very bold or Black style

```css
h1 {
    font-family:  'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem; /*Optional*/
    line-height: 1.5; /*Optional*/
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
  <!--All weights  of Montserrat & Ubuntu are included here. You can also add /remove needed-->

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  
  <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
  <p> Normal Text is much smaller then desired Montserrat-Black</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to explain what changes are required to the code in the question in order to make it work, so that your answer is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the font family and the font weight to get the actual size you want
example:

```
 h1{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
 }
```

Also, make sure that if you are using an external CSS file, its link should be placed after all the script and link tags inside the head tag. In brief, just above end of the head tag.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the font is `Monserrat`, not `Monserrat-black`.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>This is a title, styled with the h1 tag</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph, not styled with the h1 tag</p>
```

Here's the code from the little popup in the bottom-right on Google Fonts:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

font-family: "Montserrat-something"; is not working anymore .

so u need to write :
font-family: "Montserrat";
font-weight: value of font weight;

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you linked your stylesheet in the HTML file also matters. To override the default styles you must include your own stylesheet at last of all other stylesheet in the head section.

I hope it will do.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. If you got this problem from Angela Yu's Web Development Bootcamp, you should refer to topic 71. You'll notice that it's specified to use

```
h1 
{
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Black, sans-serif';
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5; 
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Or to get along as same as described in the tutorial you can either use `font-weight: bold;`

Answer (score 0):

you must keep the css file link below the bootstrap link, and every thing must be fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Google has deprecated the `font-family: 'Montserrat-Black', sans-serif;` if you wanted to use that font again please copy the following code.

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
```

If this is not working then please make sure that your CSS Style Sheet link is added after the bootstrap and any other CSS Stylesheet Link.